# AVD not starting up in android studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I'm currently installing Android studio and I've to configure AVD.
To open AVD I'm writing this command in cmd:

```
android create avd
```

but it's not working.

Also I am not able to see adv manager under

```
tools>android>avd
```

as specified in various articles.

Please guide.

Comment: Make sure it is `avd`, not `adv`.

Answer (score 1):

`android` command is deprecated

For command line tools use

```
tools\bin\avdmanager.bat
```

---

```
Android/Sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd --force --name testAVD --abi google_apis/x86_64 --package 'system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86_64'
```

For SDK you can use `tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat`